# android Radio buttons declared in code don't use default style

Tags: android, radio-button

I have an AlertDialog DialogFragment that defines some radio buttons in code and adds them to a RadioGroup. This RadioGroup has one RadioButton defined in the xml as well.

```
<RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rgSubtitleStreams"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:tag="-1"
                android:text="@string/none" />
</RadioGroup>
```

On android 5.0 devices, this looks fine when the app is running. However on Android 4.x devices, the default color scheme is ignored on the buttons defined in code. For 4.x devices I'm expecting the white variants for the button states

Android 4.x: non-uniform colors

[image]

Android 5.0: uniform colors

[image]

Comment: What values folder are you defining it in?

Comment: None. I'm not modifying the default radio button style at all.

Comment: if none in the 4.x is clicked what color is the center black or white?

Comment: I believe 4.x are not editable without drawable images. The text can be changed within java or xml.

Comment: In the 4.x. If I click one of the two lower RadioButtons they are black with the black dot. If I click the top one, which is declared in the xml, the color is the off-teal of the material theme.

Comment: Okay are you declaring all three radiobuttons in the XML or just one like the example above?  Because you might have to add all three in the xml for it to work.  Just test it out in the xml and let me know if it works?

Comment: declaring one in xml and then various amounts by code.

Comment: Do what I said and test it out to see if the ones you put in xml are the same or like what you want

Comment: I can't declare them all in xml as the amount isn't a fixed. Could be any number declared in code.

Comment: ok. I'll see what happens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65536/discussion-between-eugene-h-and-redshirt).